# Prepared Statement boolean vs. Bit Postgresql and Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have some Problems with using PostgresSQL with Java. When i have a Prepared Query and one of the parameter is boolean like "blocked" i get this error message:

> ERROR column "blocked" is Type bit but Expression has type boolean

My Code for this is:

```
else if (param instanceof Boolean)
{
    p.setBoolean(j, (boolean) param);
}
```

Any idears how to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

A Postgres `bit` is not a `boolean`. You can insert a bit value using string `1` or `0`:

```
p.setBoolean(j, param ? "1" : "0");
```

Comment: setBoolean only takes a Boolean value, so this doesn't work, however attempting to use `setString(j, param ? "1" : "0");` results in `ERROR: operator does not exist: bit = character varying `, so I'm not sure what options are left.  (setInt gives the same sort of casting error too)